# ASP.NET MVC Anti Forgery Tokens

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5, asp.net-ajax

I have asp.net MVC application in which bootstrap, telerik Kendo UI (for MVC) have also used. The controllers have  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute and in razor pages (.cshtml) following implemenation is used:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComments", "Comments", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "closeCommentsModal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    -----
    -----
    <Comment - Bootstrap model is used and here is footer example>
<div class="modal-footer buttons">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
}
```

The save button does a ajax call as below

```
function saveField(field, value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#SAVEFIELD").val(),
        data: { session: $("#SESSION").val(), field: field, value: value },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
}
```

This calls the MVC controller method which is implemented as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SaveSessionField(Guid session, string field, string value)
```

The **entire** functionality works but recently we are upgrading to **bootstrap 5.0** and now we have to modify jquery function to pass anti-frogery token to get response from MVC controller. The modified jquery function is as below:

```
function saveField(field, value) {
    var token = $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#SAVEFIELD").val(),
        data: { session: $("#SESSION").val(), field: field, value: value, '__RequestVerificationToken': token },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
}
```

My question is why **bootstrap 5 upgrade** require to pass anti frogery token separately in jquery function ? Why it was working in older version of bootstrap without passing anti frogery token ? Do we need to upgrade ajax version also to avoid passing token separately in jquery function ? I have lots of jquery functions so I don't want to modify all functions to pass token value. Do we have a global way to manage token in ASP.NET MVC project so that we can avoid changing javascript functions ?